# IBM Cloud Code Engine: Cannot reuse name of deleted project

Tags: ibm-cloud, serverless, ibm-cloud-code-engine

I deleted a project in IBM Cloud Code Engine some days ago. Now, I wanted to reuse the project name, but I am running into the following error:

```
$ ibmcloud ce project create -n foobar
FAILED
A project named 'foobar' with id 'xxxx' already exists in region 'us-south', 
resource group 'default'. Select a different name.
```

I looked into it and it shows the project as "soft deleted". What can I do to reuse the name? How do I delete the project?

```
$ ibmcloud ce project list
Getting projects...
OK

Name        ID       Status        Enabled  Selected  Tags  Region    Resource Group  Age  
foobar      xxxx     soft deleted  false    false           us-south  default         3d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that many types of resources within IBM Cloud are not deleted immediately, but retained for 7 days. The [resources can be reclaimed within that period or deleted for good](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-resource-reclamation&interface=cli).

When you delete an IBM Cloud Code Engine, you can ["hard delete" the project](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/codeengine?topic=codeengine-manage-project#delete-project). In that case it is really gone and the name can be reused immediately.

To hard delete the project use the `--hard` option:

```
ibmcloud ce project delete --name foobar --hard -f
```

Or, on your soft-deleted project, use this command to delete it for good:

- List the reclamations:
  `ibmcloud resource reclamations`
- Use the id to delete it:
  `ibmcloud resource reclamation-delete the-id-from-previous-command`